# Typescript not compiling class properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a problem with typescript. The problem is that it suddenly stopped compiling class properties to the .js file. It compiles everything, the functions the constructor but the properties aren't there.
Server.ts

```js
export class Server{
    id: String;
    prefix: String;
    constructor(){
        
    }
    copy(object){
        object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
        console.log(this);
        
        for (const k in object) {
            if(this.hasOwnProperty(k))
                this[k] = object[k];
        }
        console.log(this);
         
    }

}
```

Server.js

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.Server = void 0;
class Server {
    constructor() {
    }
    copy(object) {
        object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
        console.log(this);
        for (const k in object) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(k))
                this[k] = object[k];
        }
        console.log(this);
    }
}
exports.Server = Server;
```

Scenario.ts

```js
import { percentageChance } from "../utilities/percentageChance";
import { Champion } from "./Champion";

export class Scenario {
    name: String;
    description: String;
    champion: Champion;
    choices: string[];
    outcome: number[];
    final: string[];

    constructor(name: String, description: string | String, champion: Champion, choices: string[], outcome: number[], final: string[]) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.champion = champion;
        this.choices = choices;
        this.outcome = outcome;
        this.final = final;
    }

    calculateOutcome(choiceIndex : number) {
        if(percentageChance(this.choices, this.outcome) == this.choices[choiceIndex]){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Scenario.js

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.Scenario = void 0;
const percentageChance_1 = require("../utilities/percentageChance");
class Scenario {
    constructor(name, description, champion, choices, outcome, final) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.champion = champion;
        this.choices = choices;
        this.outcome = outcome;
        this.final = final;
    }
    calculateOutcome(choiceIndex) {
        if (percentageChance_1.percentageChance(this.choices, this.outcome) == this.choices[choiceIndex]) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
exports.Scenario = Scenario;
```

Has anyone had anything like this happened? If yes then how should it fix this?

Comment: How do you expect js files to look and what issues do you have with the current output?

Answer (score 0):

I think that one is easy, as JS is a dynamically typed language no property that was not assigned a value will be created. So typescript will leave those properties to be created on-demand.

If you put a default value in class properties, it makes them transpile to JS on compile time.

```
export class Scenario {
name: String = '';
description: String = '';
champion: Champion = new Champion();
choices: string[] = [];
outcome: number[] = [];
final: string[] = [];
//...
}
```

Had the same problem using a method to copy properties of the same values from another object, since my properties do not exist (because of absent default value) nothing was copied...

Comment: So I have to add a default value to every class? I've tested it and it works but it was working without that before.

Comment: @C4LLM3P3T3R - when asking questions regarding changes in behaviour, if you want to know *why* the change happened, you should provide relevant info: was there a change in tsconfig, how it looks like, what is the version of TS, what's your build workflow, etc.